# Trouble with importing a file with pandas read_json

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python (I'm using python 3) and I'm trying to import a JSON file in Jupyter notebook. However, it is giving the error below:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4276350: character maps to <undefined>
```

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
import json
%matplotlib inline

with open('C:\\Users/Desktop/Machine  Learning/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json') as datafile:
data = pd.read_json(datafile,orient='columns',encoding='utf-8')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show at least how the JSON file looks like? That way we can all see where the problem is.

Comment: Hi mmontoya,the link from where I got the dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset    Dataset:yelp_academic_dataset_business.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/melqkiades/yelp/master/notebooks/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json) is the file you're trying to import, it is actually many JSON objects, one per line. You need to import it line by line by specifying `lines=True`:

```
data = pd.read_json(datafile, lines=True, orient='columns', encoding='utf-8')
```

Also, pass the file path as the first argument, not the file contents. You can get rid of the code for opening the file. Furthermore, `pd.read_json` is returning a DataFrame, there is no need for that last line of your program:

```
>>> data = pd.read_json('yelp_academic_dataset_business.json', lines=True, orient='columns', encoding='utf-8')
>>> data
                                              attributes             business_id                                         categories             city    ...    review_count stars  state      type
0      {'Take-out': False, 'Wi-Fi': 'free', 'Good For...  O_X3PGhk3Y5JWVi866qlJg  [Active Life, Arts & Entertainment, Stadiums &...          Phoenix    ...              29   4.0     AZ  business
1      {'Parking': {'garage': False, 'street': False,...  QbrM7wqtmoNncqjc6GtFaQ  [Tires, Automotive, Fashion, Shopping, Departm...         Glendale    ...               3   3.5     AZ  business
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes that is the file I'm trying to import. However, it still gives the same error :(

Comment: @Lonewolf Pass the file path as the first arg to `read_json`, not the file contents.

Comment: with open('C:\\Users/Desktop/Machine Learning/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json') as datafile:
  data = pd.read_json('yelp_academic_dataset_business.json', lines=True, orient='columns', encoding='utf-8')              This is the code I have, and it is not working. The error I'm getting is "ValueError: Expected object or value"

Comment: You need to specify the whole path if it is not in the same directory as the program.. `pd.read_json('C:/Users/Desktop/Machine Learning/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json', lines=True, orient='columns', encoding='utf-8')` , make sure you confirm that is the correct path to the file.